# inner html gets rendered before populating property value

Tags: angular, binding, components

I have a library made of componentA and templateA.
In templateA I'm binding a property of componentA, through innerhtml binding.
There is a function populate(obj) which receives an object 'options' and then uses it to get a value useful to set the property.

ComponentA.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-sqv',
  templateUrl: './templateA.component.html'

})

export class SqvLibComponent {

   seq: string;

   populate(op: Options): void {

    ----some other functions---

     this.seq = 'someData';
}
```

ComponentB.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './templateB.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 ngOnInit() {


    let options = { someValue }

    const s: SqvLibComponent = new SqvLibComponent();
    s.populate(options);

  }
}
```

TemplateB has the selector < lib-sqv >.

TemplateA view gets rendered before the property this.seq receives a value.

I've noticed that if I give a value to this.seq inside the constructor,  the value gets displayed in the view.
So I'm trying to pass options to the constuctor like so:

ComponentB.ts

```
new SqvLibComponent(options);
```

And then in ComponentA.ts

```
export class SqvLibComponent {

  public constructor(public op: Options) {
  this.populate(op);
  }
}
```

But this gives errors about the object I'm trying to pass.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ngIf` to avoid rendering `TemplateA` before the property `this.seq` receives a value.

```
<ng-container ngIf="seq">
    <templateA></templateA>
</ng-container>
```

[As Angular documentation says:](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

> ngIf is structural directive that conditionally includes a template based on
>   the value of an expression coerced to Boolean. When the expression
>   evaluates to true, Angular renders the template provided in a then
>   clause, and when false or null, Angular renders the template provided
>   in an optional else clause. The default template for the else clause
>   is blank.

UPDATE:

In Angular 7 `*ngIf` directive need to be provided explicitly into your module like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
```

OR:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
```

As BrowserModule exports CommonModule

Comment: Now it says: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
I'm using Angular 7, maybe it is a problem with versions?
I will look further into this to find something similar. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: As far as I know you should not use "this" in your template. Just "seq"

Comment: So, I've imported CommonModule and I'm using just "seq" in the template.
Now the error is:
"Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!"

Comment: @MartinaBevilacqua It looks like you are using some other directives in your component. Try to use like that `<ng-container ngIf="seq">
    <templateA></templateA>
</ng-container>`

Comment: Unfortunately the error persist. 
I get many warnings about this file: sqvLibrary/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js. It says it is a critical dependency...

Comment: @MartinaBevilacqua please, see this tutorial https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-ngif-example and make all imports like author of this article did.

Comment: At the end I've solved using a directive in templateB <sqv-lib [op] = "this.options">, then using @Input() op: Options and implementing Oninit in componentA.